# Can Godot files be implemented in Python3.7.6

Tags: python-3.x, godot

Simple question (I hope): Can Godot files be implemented in Python3.7.6?

I see that there are modules for accessing Python from Godot, but is there a binding for the opposite usage?

Answer (score 0):

Logic (and searching) forces me to conclude that there would no rational basis for importing the Godot touch-screen functionality (from Godot files) into Python.  Godot represents the 'end-user' interface.  We've accomplished our goal of numerical input in Qt with Python based on our Godot work.  Q.E.D.